# How to mock database for testing in xUnit?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, xunit, dbcontext

I have the following `DbContext`:

```cs
public class OrganizerDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public OrganizerDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrganizerDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
 
    // list of dbSet<> here

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasOne(a => a.Accesses)
            .WithOne(a => a.User)
            .HasForeignKey<UserAccess>(a => a.UserId);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasOne(a=>a.EmploymentStatus)
            .WithOne(a=>a.User)
            .HasForeignKey<EmploymentStatus>(a => a.UserId);

        builder.Entity<EmploymentStatus>()
            .HasOne(a=>a.Facility)
            .WithMany(a=>a.Employments)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.FacilityId);        
    }
}
```

In my xUnit test, I used `FakeItEasy` and have following code:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task AnnouncerIndex_Test_1()
{
    // Arrange
    var fakeContext = A.Fake<OrganizerDbContext>();
    var fakeUserManager = A.Fake<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    var controller = new AnnouncementsController(fakeContext, fakeUserManager);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.IsUserBlockedFromAccesingAnnouncer();

    // Assert
    Assert.False(result);
}
```

The test fails and I get this in test details summary:

> Message: 
> FakeItEasy.Core.FakeCreationException :
> Failed to create fake of type Organizer3.Data.OrganizerDbContext: Below is a list of reasons for failure per attempted constructor:
> Constructor with signature (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Organizer3.Data.OrganizerDbContext]) failed:       No constructor matches the passed arguments for constructor.       An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was caught during this call. Its message was:       The DbContextOptions passed to the OrganizerDbContextProxy constructor must be a DbContextOptions<OrganizerDbContextProxy>. When registering multiple DbContext types, make sure that the constructor for each context type has a DbContextOptions<TContext> parameter rather than a non-generic DbContextOptions parameter.          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserContext`5..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`8..ctor(DbContextOptions options)          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`3..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(DbContextOptions options)          at Organizer3.Data.OrganizerDbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in C:\Users\Smokiel\Desktop\Organizer3\Organizer3\Areas\Identity\Data\OrganizerDbContext.cs:line 15
> at Castle.Proxies.OrganizerDbContextProxy..ctor(IInterceptor[] , DbContextOptions`1 options)
>
> Stack Trace: 
> FailedCreationResult.get_Result() line 82
> FakeAndDummyManager.CreateFake(Type typeOfFake, Action`1 optionsBuilder, LoopDetectingResolutionContext resolutionContext) line 42
> FakeAndDummyManager.CreateFake(Type typeOfFake, LoopDetectingResolutionContext resolutionContext) line 28
> A.FakeT line 31
> AnnouncementsControllerTests.AnnouncerIndex_Test_1() line 28
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---

I tried adding empty constructor by adding
`public OrganizerDbContext() { }`  to DbContext, after running test again i got this summary:

> Message:  System.ArgumentException : Object 'Organizer3.Controllers.AnnouncementsController' of type Organizer3.Controllers.AnnouncementsController is not recognized as a fake object.    Stack Trace:  DefaultFakeManagerAccessor.GetFakeManager(Object proxy) line 28 Fake.GetFakeManager(Object fakedObject) line 28 FakeConfigurationManager.GuardAgainstNonFake(Object target) line 83 FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo[T](Expression`1 callSpecification) line 45 A.CallTo[T](Expression`1 callSpecification) line 161 AnnouncementsControllerTests.AnnouncerIndex_Test_1() line 34 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---

I expected to get a dummy context I could use for testing, it wasn't called anywhere outside of controller constructor, and I can't get it running.

Comment: I've updated my answer , and if I don't set the property  public virtual DbSet<WebApplication6.Models.SomeEntity>? SomeEntity { get; set; }  as Virtual ,it would get the same error in your another case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104731/fakeiteasy-class-containing-fake-method-not-recognized-as-a-fake-object-problem Hopes could help

Answer (score 1):

as the error indicates

```
A.Fake<OrganizerDbContext>();
```

Would not pass the parameters which are required to the constructor of DbContext

you have to pass DbContextOptions<> to the contructor of the dbcontext like below

```
A.Fake<WebApplication6Context>(x => x.WithArgumentsForConstructor(new object[] { options }));
```

I tried as below,hopes could help:

The Action in controller :

```
 public List<SomeEntity> GetEntities()
        {
              return  _context.SomeEntity.ToList();
        }
```

The Dbcontext:

```
public class WebApplication6Context : DbContext
    {
        public WebApplication6Context (DbContextOptions<WebApplication6Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<WebApplication6.Models.SomeEntity>? SomeEntity { get; set; } 

        
    }
```

Codes related with Test

```
[Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {

            

            var data = new List<SomeEntity>() { new SomeEntity() { Id = 1, Name = "N1" }, new SomeEntity() { Id = 2, Name = "N2" } }.AsQueryable();

            var fakeDbSet = A.Fake<DbSet<SomeEntity>>(x=> 
            { 
               
                x.Implements(typeof(IQueryable<SomeEntity>));
                x.Implements(typeof(IEnumerable<SomeEntity>));
               
            });
            
            A.CallTo(() => ((IQueryable<SomeEntity>)fakeDbSet).GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            
            var fakecontext = A.Fake<WebApplication6Context>(x =>
            {
                x.WithArgumentsForConstructor(new object[] {  new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WebApplication6Context>().Options });

            });
            
            A.CallTo(() => fakecontext.SomeEntity).Returns(fakeDbSet);
            var controller = new SomeEntitiesController(fakecontext);
            //Act
            var result=controller.GetEntities();
            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(2,result.Count);

        }
```

The Result:

[image]