# FakeItEasy class containing fake method not recognized as a fake object problem

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, xunit, fakeiteasy

I have this code:

```
[Fact]
public async Task AnnouncerIndex_Test_1()
{
    //Arrange

    var fakeContext = A.Fake<OrganizerDbContext>();
    var fakeUserManager = A.Fake< UserManager<AppUser>>();
    var controller = new AnnouncementsController(fakeContext, fakeUserManager);
    

    A.CallTo(() => controller
                    .IsUserBlockedFromAccesingAnnouncer("aaa"))
                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(false));

    
    //Act
    //some code
     
    //Assert
    //some code

}
```

I want to run unit tests on methods in my controller, the method I'm testing calls another one and I want to replace value it returns with predefinied one using A.CallTo(()=>). But instead I'm getting informed that tested controller isn't a fake object, after running test I get this summary:

```
System.ArgumentException : Object 'Organizer3.Controllers.AnnouncementsController' of type Organizer3.Controllers.AnnouncementsController is not recognized as a fake object.

  Stack Trace: 
DefaultFakeManagerAccessor.GetFakeManager(Object proxy) line 28
Fake.GetFakeManager(Object fakedObject) line 28
FakeConfigurationManager.GuardAgainstNonFake(Object target) line 83
FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo[T](Expression`1 callSpecification) line 45
A.CallTo[T](Expression`1 callSpecification) line 161
AnnouncementsControllerTests.AnnouncerIndex_Test_1() line 32
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

I also tried creating fake controller, but doing so doesn't alow me to test methods inside it.

```
var fakeController =A.Fake<AnnouncementsController>();           
A.CallTo(() => fakeController
                .IsUserBlockedFromAccesingAnnouncer("aaa"))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(false));
```

Test summary:

```
FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationException : 

  The current proxy generator can not intercept the method Organizer3.Controllers.AnnouncementsController.IsUserBlockedFromAccesingAnnouncer(System.String CUID) for the following reason:
    - Non-virtual members can not be intercepted. Only interface members and virtual, overriding, and abstract members can be intercepted.



  Stack Trace: 
DefaultInterceptionAsserter.AssertThatMethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget) line 23
FakeConfigurationManager.AssertThatMemberCanBeIntercepted(ParsedCallExpression parsed) line 96
FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo[T](Expression`1 callSpecification) line 46
A.CallTo[T](Expression`1 callSpecification) line 161
AnnouncementsControllerTests.AnnouncerIndex_Test_1() line 36
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Comment: Firstly,I don't think it's proper to Setup the controller you are testing,When it comes to the first error:AnnouncementsController is not recognized as a fake object , it indicates you could only setup the fake object created like A.Fake<SomeClass>,To fix the second error :Only interface members and virtual, overriding, and abstract members can be intercepted.,try to set it  virtual

Comment: Using controller interface instead of controller class fixed the issue. Thank you @RuikaiFeng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt doesn't work because, as mentioned by the error message, your `new AnnouncementsController` is not a fake, it's an actual instance of the class, so it can't be configured by FakeItEasy.

The second attempt (using a fake `AnnouncementsController`) could work, but you'd need to change `IsUserBlockedFromAccesingAnnouncer` to make it virtual, so that FakeItEasy can fake it. Also, you would also need to pass the fake dependencies to it, like this:

```cs
var fakeController = A.Fake<AnnouncementsController>(options =>
    options.WithArgumentsForConstructor(() => new AnnouncementsController(fakeContext, fakeUserManager)));
```